# How come ajax fails to post a string?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to implement a popup with a text field that will allow for the creation of a new option in a dropdown menu without submitting the form.  It's not quite working.  The key problem seems to be that I can't get the string new_option to php.  How come the $_POST array is empty in the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup ({  
  cache: false  
});

$('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').click( function() {

  // Show modal window
  $('#add-new').modal('show');
  $('#add-new-submit').on('click', function() {

    // Get new option from text field
    var new_option = $('#add-new-text').val();
    console.log(new_option);


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/upload_page",
      data: {new_option:'new_option'}
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    });

    $('#add-new').modal('toggle');                            
  });

}); 

</script>


<?php
$new_option = $_POST['new_option']; # <----- Gives Undefined index error
                  //var_dump($new_option);

// When I get this working this is how I'll get $new_option
if(isset($new_option))
{
  $new_option = $_POST['new_option'];
  $species = array($new_option => $new_option) + $species;
  //print_r($new_option);
  //print_r($species);
  var_dump($new_option);
}

?>
```

In the console I see the entered string (new_option), but php gives an error (Undefined index: new_option) at $new_option = $_POST['new_option'].  I've tried a gazillion things and can't seem to get new_option over to php.  Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks in advance your help!

Comment: @JonRed - no, if that was the case, then you would never be able to send more than one piece of data.

Comment: Try adding the `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` output?

Comment: The `data: {new_option:'new_option'}` line is wrong (it sends the string `"new_option"` instead of the value), but I am puzzled why it isn't sent at all. Are quotes around the key mandatory in javascript?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yeah, that's the main problem here, and all the answers don't seem to see it... The key quotes are optional, this thing should pass the string (or whatever) normally.

Comment: Could you try `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: @Shomz var_dump($_POST) outputs "array(0) { }"

Comment: Then none of your data is being sent, for some reason, no matter what the key name is, what the value is (and every other bull* that the answers suggest). If I were you, I'd start with the most basic ajax call and work it out from there... You probably overlooked something and made a silly error.

Comment: Would be nice to know if there are some news about this, did you got your code working?

Comment: @Manuel:  Thanks for you comments and help!  I did ajax working and have moved onto other problems with binding/unbinding (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889716/modal-unbind-on-fade) where you can see my working ajax code which I had to modify to pass an array in addition to a string.  Your help on that as-of-yet unresolved issue would be much appreciated too! :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things I see wrong with your AJAX request:

1, URL

currently your using:

`url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/upload_page",`

You need to ensure that the URL is correct, if you look at the source code, does it look correct and can you go to that URL if you paste it into your browser. I'm presuming that you are using WordPress' `site_url()` which does not add the slash after the domain. Possible solution:

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>main/upload_page",
```

2, DATA

currently your using:
`data: {new_option:'new_option'}`

This will send a `POST['new_option'] = 'new_option';`. You need to remove the single quotes from around the value:

```
data: {new_option:new_option}
```

Comment: That's why I mentioned that he needs to be able to go to the URL if he looks at it in his source code

Comment: That is true - however I think the URL is correct since it does output the error, right?

Comment: If the URL is incorrect, he should get either a 404 or see something completely unexpected

Comment: if he is using Wordpress' `site_url()` function then his url target will go to `http://www.example.commain/upload_page` rather than `http://www.example.com/main/upload_page`

Comment: @SamuelCook If the URL is wrong then he should be getting that 404, but the OP is getting an Undefined index error. Which means that the URL is correct. I think that's what Shomz is trying to say.

Comment: Just like @TimothyOnggowasito said - whatever the URL it lands on, it's obviously returning the result of OPs script. The only scenario where this should be of any concern is if there are two similar scripts on those two possible landing pages, which is highly unlikely.

Comment: With both url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/upload_page" and url: '' I see a POST in the console to the correct page, which is the page with the ajax call in it (if that wasn't clear before).  Removing the single quotes in the data line does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one by changing `ajax` variable name also remove the single quotes `'` arround the variable

```
 var new_option_to_send = $('#add-new-text').val();
```

And in `ajax` call

```
 data: {new_option:new_option_to_send }
```

Comment: @Shomz, The problem is on javascript side, not PHP.

Comment: Its just a try :) i haven't mention that this will solve the problem

Comment: Haha, answers are supposed to solve problems. :)
@ocanal: JS side is practically the same - `index: some_string`... and please read the question - **the problem is on the php side**

Answer (score 0):

After reading your Question and all the current Answers and comments, the only conclusion i could make is that all the code you've posted above is in the same file.

So `$_POST['new_option']` will be undefined when you first visiting the page, but should be defined when you send the request.

Just change your code to use `isset()` to check for the value to be set before accessing it and the error should be gone.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['new_option'])) {
  // Do your stuff here
}
```

//EDIT

In general it's not a problem to have that code in the same File, but don't expect $_POST data to be defined when requesting the page with your Browser, because there is non.

When you open the Page with your Browser it will send a GET request to your Server, your Server will search for the according PHP-Script and pass it to the PHP-Processor, along with all the informations contained in the Request.
So Processor will process that Script executing all the PHP code in it and passing back the outcome to your the Webserver, which will deliver it to your Browser.
The Data your Browser will receive doesn't contain any PHP-Code anymore.

Now you change an option in your form. That will trigger your Javascript code, which send's an AJAX-Request to your server, calling the same URL. But this time it's a POST-Request containing your data. The process is pretty much the same, but now the variable is set and so will be evaluated by the PHP-Processor. And the response is sent to your your Javascript code.

If you want to save the received data, just check for the Request method/if your variable is set and save it if it is saved.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
?>

  // your html/javascript stuff here

<?php
} else if (isset($_POST['new_value']) {

  // do whatever you want with the received data

} else { // Not a valid request for this Script, send according HTTP-Status  
  http_response_code(400); // or header(' ', true, 400); if you're using a PHP-Version < 5.4.0 
}
```

If you wan't to change anything in the Document the user is currently viewing in his Browser based on his choosen option you'll need to do it with JavaScript. PHP only runs on the Server side and thus has no influence on anything on the Client's PC.

To check if your POST request was progressed as expected try this:

1. add `echo $_POST['new_option'];` in the `else if` branch
2. open your page with Chrome
3. open the the Developer Tools (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)
4. open the Network tab
5. set filter to XHR
6. trigger your request by changing your option
7. now a new request should popup in that list
8. click on it

Now you should see the response from the server to your POST request, if the response contains the value that you sended, your code works

Comment: When I do this it never gets set (since $_POST is empty), even though I see my string in the console after I enter a new option in the popup.  And, yes, this code is all in the same file.  Is that the issue?  What do I need to differently if it's all in the same file?

Comment: Sure it won't get set on the request the Page with your Browser, since it's a GET-Request and not sending Data to the Server. When you see your string in the console it will mean that your code works since that is the response to your request, but you can't expect PHP setting the variable in the Document you're viewing with your Browser at that Moment since that Document is already generated and send to you.

Comment: I edited the answer to do explain it a bit further. Please mark it as answer if it helped you solving your problem/improve your understanding of PHP :)

Comment: I tried this code and got it to run (had to remove the initial "$request_is_get = (" (not sure why it is there) but the POST array is still always empty and so I never get to the else if branch to process the received data.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, forgot to remove it. About your empty $_POST, are you sure that the array is empty when you're sending the POST request and not the initial GET request? I edited my answer and added a way to check that in case you're not sure.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I installed Chromium and tried your steps but in Chromium my modal window doesn't even come up when I select Add New and so I can't check anything yet.  Trying to figure out why the window comes up in Firefox (and other browsers) and not in Chromium.  Is there a way of checking requests with Firefox's developer tools?

Comment: I'm not sure about Firefoxs build-in tools, but you can do it with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 0):

OK try those following steps:

1) Open google crome browser and goto your app link

2) press Ctrl+Shift+J it will open crome's debugger. select Network tab. do not close this debuger untill step#4

3) Open up your modal form, and click to submit.

4) Ajax request will be shown in network tab. click on it will show u header/preview/respnse. in header check Request URL is it correct? if not you got your bug!

5) So the url is correct, i presume. click on Response tab what u see? var_dump($_POST) gives an empty array and var_dump($new_option) gives bool(false)?

6) Open your controllers(main) method(upload) and write the following code inside upload method:

```
if($this->input->post()){
     $new_option=$this->input->post("new_option");
     //do what u want to do with it.
}else{ 
     //no posting at all? lets see what u got
     var_dump($_REQUEST);
}
```

7) Re do from step#1 to step#5

i think it will solve your problem or at least you may know whats going on..

Answer (score -1):

first of all modify data vars like:

```
data: "new_option="+new_option, // like url encoding
```

secondly, is it codeigniter code?

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

then in the controller "main/upload_page" try:

```
$new_option = $this->input->post('new_option'); // only for codeigniter no other framework
```

also, for debugging js+php ajax call use crome browser. it will show u the request and response in Network(Ctrl+Shift+J) tab. try the following code at PHP end so u can see the output in network tab

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Yes this is Codeigniter.  I tried $new_option = $this->input->post('new_option'); but still get the same error.  var_dump($_POST) gives an empty array and var_dump($new_option) gives bool(false).